# Python не запускает сервер

Tags: python, сервер, flask

Я понимаю что, возможно вопрос глуповат, но так как в три строчки кода сервер не запускается, без понятныx мне причин, приходиться обращаться к вам)

Flask установил на Python 3.7

И вот код:

```
from flask import Flask#, jsonify, request

# Создаем экземпляр узла
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='197.0.0.0', port=1200)
```

И вот что Я получаю:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/I/PitoneWork/Tests.py", line 13, in <module>
>     app.run(host='197.0.0.0', port=1200)
>   File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 938, in run
>     cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
>   File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 629, in show_server_banner
>     click.echo(message)
>   File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 217, in echo
>     file = _default_text_stdout()
>   File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 621, in func
>     rv = wrapper_func()
>   File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 385, in get_text_stdout
>     rv = _get_windows_console_stream(sys.stdout, encoding, errors)
>   File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 261, in _get_windows_console_stream
>     func = _stream_factories.get(f.fileno())
> io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
> ```

Высылайте подмогу, плыз)

Comment: Странный хост и порт. А просто `app.run()` работает?

Comment: Просто app.run() выдает точно такой же результат((

Comment: Такая проблема не только у вас: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2771 . Как скрипт запускали? Через IDLE Python IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока `fileno()` метод работает с нормальными `IO` объектами (`sys.stdout`, `sys.stderr`, `sys.stdin`, `socket.socket`) `IDLE Python IDE` подменяет ваши `IO` объекты, что собственно и ломает запуск.

Поэтому, если вы получили эту ошибку - запустите код просто из питона.

Comment: Отсюда взяли ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081957/5909792 ? :)

Comment: @gil9red Я читал правила и там написано, что можно перевести из stackoverflow.com, что так же можно вставлять в ответ, так как написано на русском языке. Поэтому - да, ответ взять оттуда. Но эту проблему я и там знал раньше, просто не помнил весь список IO объектов, которые ломает IDLE, потому что сам с ним какое-то время мучался.

Comment: Вы как будто оправдываетесь :) Все правильно сделали, просто когда искал проблему автора наткнулся на тот ответ, и тут прочитал ваш с некоторым дежавю, вот из интереса спросил :)

Comment: @gil9red Это не оправдание - это просто описание 2 минут моей жизни. ) Может вам это как-то тоже поможет, в будущем. )

Comment: "запустите код просто из питона" - Python shell?

Comment: @Shadow Ну да, например, `python3 a.py`.

Comment: Я сделал что вы сказали, он робит?) Я просто первый раз на питоне)

 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: @Shadow Супер! Примите ответ тогда, пожалуйста, если она вам помог. )

Comment: А тогда ещё вопрос, а что делать если код ОЧЕНЬ большой то и ему требуется запуск сервера?? Так же запускать в PitonShell?? ((

Comment: @Shadow Я дам вам простой совет, как я запускаю огромные проекты на python + flask - поставьте себе Jetbrains PyCharm Community Edition. Он бесплатный и поверьте, вы полюбите питон. )

Comment: А есть что-нибдуь другое? Я уже попробовал эту Ide и оно не капец как не удобно)

Comment: @Shadow лучше этой я честно говоря не знаю.

Comment: Только что протестировал Microsoft Visual Studio- вроде нормально робит с питоном) Я не сразу заметил там модули для него)